# Chrome Permissions

Tags: javascript, nfc

I want to create a pop-up message to the user to allow permissions for NFC reader to be read from a webpage. 
I have Javascript code written and linked to the html, but no pop-up is activated on any of the requests.

I'm not getting the pop up to fire, I want to get it working on all browsers and smart phones.

These are my console log errors.
Uncaught ReferenceError: NDEFReader is not defined at permissions.js:73
permissions.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'query' on 'Permissions': GenericSensorExtraClasses flag is not enabled.
    at checkPermission (permissions.js:17)
    at permissions.js:36

```
    if ('permissions' in navigator) {
    var logTarget = document.getElementById('logTarget');

    function handleChange(permissionName, newState) {
        var timeBadge = new Date().toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
        var newStateInfo = document.createElement('p');
        newStateInfo.innerHTML = '' + timeBadge + ' State of ' + permissionName + ' permission status changed to ' + newState + '.';
        logTarget.appendChild(newStateInfo);
    }

    function checkPermission(permissionName, descriptor) {
        try {
            navigator.permissions.query(Object.assign({ name: permissionName }, descriptor))
                .then(function (permission) {
                    document.getElementById(permissionName + '-status').innerHTML = permission.state;
                    permission.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
                        document.getElementById(permissionName + '-status').innerHTML = permission.state;
                        handleChange(permissionName, permission.state);
                    });
                });
        } catch (e) {
        }
    }

    checkPermission('geolocation');
    checkPermission('notifications');
    checkPermission('push', { userVisibleOnly: true });
    checkPermission('midi', { sysex: true });
    checkPermission('background-sync');
    checkPermission('ambient-light-sensor');
    checkPermission('accelerometer');
    checkPermission('gyroscope');
    checkPermission('magnetometer');
    checkPermission('nfc');

    var noop = function () { };
    navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);

    function requestGeolocation() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(noop);
    } function requestNotifications() {
        Notification.requestPermission();
    } function requestPush() {
        navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration()
            .then(function (serviceWorkerRegistration) {
                serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe();
            });
    } function requestMidi() {
        navigator.requestMIDIAccess({ sysex: true });
    } function requestCamera() {
        navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true }, noop, noop)
    } function requestMicrophone() {
        navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true }, noop, noop)
    } function requestNfc() {
    Notification.requestPermission();
}
} const reader = new NDEFReader()
    reader.scan(options)
    reader.addEventListener('reading', listener)
    reader.addEventListener('error', listener)
const writer = new NDEFWriter()
    writer.write(message, options)
```

Comment: Are you missing code from top or bottom? NDEFReader isn't defined on line line 73 but there aren't 73 lines of code here. Can you include all the code? Alternately... indicate the line in your code with comments so we know at least that. Please take a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You may also need to check out [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

- For now only Chrome canary on android supports the NFC reader.
- To activate this feature on this canary version you need to either provide a token (on the page or on the server's page response header) or to explicitly enable the feature as describe here: https://web.dev/nfc/#use
- The page must be served through Https